# Let $A$ be a domain, and $M$ a finite $A$-module. If $M\otimes_A{A_\mathfrak{p}}=0$, is there an $a\in{A\smallsetminus{\mathfrak{p}}}$ s.t. $aM=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand the proof of Proposition 4.1.29 of Q. Liu's book "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves."

Let $A$ be an integral domain, and ${\mathfrak{p}}\subset{A}$ a prime ideal. We let $A_{\mathfrak{p}}=S^{-1}A$ denote the localization of $A$ with respect to $S:=A\smallsetminus\mathfrak{p}$.

I want to prove the following claim:

If $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module and $M\otimes_A{A_\mathfrak{p}}=0$, then there exists an $a\in{A\smallsetminus{\mathfrak{p}}}$ such that $aM=0$.

Please prove this.

Comment: But what have *you* tried?

Comment: Please edit your title to make it clear, as the punctuations in the math expressions are disordered. Please also provide more context, how much do you know so far about the material you're reading? Show your own thoughts and attempts.

Comment: Hint : If $F$ is a sheaf, and $s \in F(U)$ has zero stalk at a point $p$, then, $s$ and $0$ are equivalent in $F_p$. Apply this to $\widetilde{M}$ and a generating set for $M$.

Comment: Let $K$ be the fraction field of $A$, so $M \otimes_A K$ is a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space (because $M$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module).  Show $M \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak p} = 0$ implies $M \otimes_A K = 0$ and prove the property $M \otimes_A K = 0$ implies $M$ is a torsion $A$-module by showing when $M$ is *not* a torsion $A$-module that there is an $A$-linear mapping from $M \otimes_A K$ *onto* a suitable nonzero $A$-module, so $M \otimes_A K \not= 0$.

Comment: As others have indicated, it would help to improve your question to indicate what you know and what you've attempted to solve the problem. Also, people often don't appreciate imperative statements (even politely phrased ones!) on a Q and A site where people are volunteering their time to help. I'd gently suggest removing the "prove this" order at the end of your post, and replace it with an actual math question. In the interest of actually being helpful math-wise, I'd suggest two hints:
1. Rewrite $M \otimes_{A} A_{p}$ in an equivalent way which should help you better understand when an...

Comment: element is $0$. (Sub-hint: what is $M \otimes_{A} S^{-1}A$ isomorphic to for any multiplicative subset $S \subset A$?) 
2. Once you've done $1$, consider a finite list of generators $m_{1}, \ldots, m_{n}$ for $M$. Then, using hint $1$, see if you can't produce elements $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n} \in A$ such that $a_{i}m_{i} = 0$. Then see if you can use these $a_{i}$s to produce your $a$.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705409/localization-of-a-module-is-zero-implies-the-multiplicatively-closed-subset-cont and many others. Please use the search function before posting and answering in comments.